# Webkit WebAudio invalidStateError DOM Exception 11 when calling bufferSource.start

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, webkit, web-audio-api

I have a metronome app that was working and is published to iTunes. When ios 9 came out, it broke my app.   It also breaks on OSX after upgrading to 10.11.2 as well.  I download Mac Chrome and the same code works fine. So it is broken in Webkit/Safari.

If I create a bufferSourceNode and then call start on the node, I receive the error 'invalidStateError DOM Exception 11'.

There are issues reported with ios and WebAudio in relating to the touchend / touchstart events.  Apparently, Apple changed the API that it required the first event to be a touchend interaction.  I'm not sure if this is what is breaking my code. I tried the workaround but to no avail ( WebAudio user-gesture restriction is no longer lifted by touchstart event :  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149367).

Does anyone have any clues or workarounds as to this issue?

Thanks,
bruce

Answer (score 1):

I discovered my problem was an issue in audioContextMonkeyPatch.js that I was using for iPhone.

The start() method takes 3 parameters and I was only passing 1 parameter to the method.  iPhone 8 accepted that ok, however when upgrading to iPhone 9,  the underlying Safari call failed because of the undefined parameter.  I put a check into the shim codes and everything resolved.